# result Incomprehensible of sql query

Tags: sql

I have anther problem of writting query Sql
I have two tables: 
candidat_test_answerand and answer, formatted as follows.

```
id_question || id_answer  ||id_test || id_candidat || date

|  1        ||  1         ||17      ||     1       ||2014-06-01
|  1        ||  2         ||17      ||     1       ||2014-06-01
|  3        ||  NULL      ||17      ||     1       ||2014-06-01
|  1        ||  7         ||18      ||     1       ||2014-06-03

id_answer   || choice_answer   || correct|| id_question     
|  1        ||  2              ||  1     ||     1      
|  2        ||  5              ||  0     ||     1       
|  3        ||  6              ||  0     ||     1           
|  4        ||  7              ||  0     ||     1     
|  5        ||  3              ||  0     ||     2         
|  6        ||  1              ||  0     ||     2     
|  7        ||  xxx            ||  1     ||     3  
|  8        ||  ttt            ||  0     ||     3      


select id_question,id_answer,choice_answer,correct,id_test,id_candidat,date from    candidat_test_reponse ctr  left join answer p  on  ID_cand=1 and ID_Test=17 and  p.ID_answer=ctr.ID_onswer and ctr.date='2014-06-01'
```

my query display

```
id_question || id_answer  || choice_answer ||correct ||id_test || id_candidat || date
|  1        ||  1         ||   1           ||    1   ||17      ||     1       ||2014-06-01
|  1        ||  2         ||    2          ||    0   ||17      ||     1       ||2014-06-01
|  3        ||  NULL      ||               ||        ||17      ||     1       ||2014-06-01
|  1        ||  7         ||               ||    1   ||18      ||     1       ||2014-06-03
```

I don't understand that line (in my query i have this condition ctr.date='2014-06-01 and ID_Test=17)

```
|  1        ||  7         ||               ||    1   ||18      ||     1       ||2014-06-03
```

Comment: please format your question better to make it readable - look at other sql-tagged questions for examples if required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is:

```
select id_question,id_answer,choice_answer,correct,id_test,id_candidat,date
from candidat_test_reponse ctr  left join
     answer p 
     on  ID_cand=1 and ID_Test=17 and  p.ID_answer=ctr.ID_onswer and ctr.date='2014-06-01'
```

You are doing a `left join`.  That means that the query keeps everything in the first table, regardless of whether or not the condition is true.  This applies to conditions on the first table as well as the second.

You can change the `join` to an `inner join` to do the filtering you want:

```
select id_question, id_answer, choice_answer, correct, id_test, id_candidat, date
from candidat_test_reponse ctr inner join
     answer p 
     on  ID_cand=1 and ID_Test=17 and  p.ID_answer=ctr.ID_onswer and ctr.date='2014-06-01'
```

Or, your intention might be:

```
select id_question, id_answer, choice_answer, correct, id_test, id_candidat, date
from candidat_test_reponse ctr left join
     answer p 
     on  ID_cand = 1 and p.ID_answer = ctr.ID_onswer
where ID_Test = 17 and ctr.date = '2014-06-01' ;
```

Comment: if I change left join to inner join 
query will not display  rows  containing ID_ansewer = NULL

Comment: @whitebackground . . . In that case, the last query with both `left join` and `where` should solve your problem.

Comment: thanx, your answer is helpful